# Как привязать свойство border елементу при hover?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Есть 3 дропдауна, сделанные на bootstrap(код одного из них):

```
<div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropdown-filter  dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="filter-name">BUTTON</span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu ">                          
                            <li class="cat-item">
                                <div class="custom-checkbox">
                                    <dd>
                                        <input id="id1" type="checkbox"
                                               class="sort"                                        
                                               name="name" value="val"/>
                                        <label for="id1"></label>
                                       Item

                                    </dd>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Хочу сделать следующее: при наведении мыши у `button` должны появляться `border` слева, сверху и справа, у `ul` в это же время с помощью `css` я убираю border-top. Эти дропдауны активируются не по клику а при наведениии курсора, т.е. по `hover`. Я попробовал кнопке выставлять `border` с помощью селектора  с `:hover`, но возникла проблема-когда с самой кнопки уводишь курсор вниз к примеру, то ховер кнопки пропадает. Как можно реализовать это?

Answer (score 0):

```
hover срабатывает только на себя и дочерние элементы

сделай так  .dropdown-filter:nth-child(1):hover ~ .dropdown-menu{
/*тут надо прорисать стили для .dropdown-menu*/
}

.dropdown-filter: hover{/*тут надо прорисать стили для .dropdown-filter*/ }

nth-child(NUMBER):hover   NUMBER - это цифра под каким номером сам элемент в дереве
```